# Force Appendix not to appear but keep references to appendix and citations in appendix

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing, citing, appendices

My research group is trying to submit a paper to a new journal and they have a strange requirement that we haven’t figured out a way to satisfy.

They would like the appendix to be a separate document. And they would like Tex files to compile themselves (they wont just accept the PDFs)

The issue here is that in the main body of the text we have references to the appendix and in the appendix we have additional citations that appear in the references.

Is there any way to force Tex to not display the appendix, but keep references to it and keep citations contained in it?

We really don’t want to have to manually insert all references (I.e. instead of using \ref{}) and manually construct the bibliography instead of using bibtex.

Cheers

Comment: make the appendix a separate doc and use xr and xcite packages to reference from the main document

Comment: I was working on this project in overleaf and thankfully they have the xr package. Haven’t been able to get xcite to work yet.  Thanks!